# Python Multithreading to allow user to exit at anytime

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a text based RPG, and I am using Python 3.3.4. It will be played through the Python command line, with no graphics. I'm wanting to make it so that no matter what options the user is presented with, they have the capability of typing "exit" or "help" and exiting (or getting help information) respectively at any time during the game. So if they're in the middle of fighting some monster and the only options presented to them directly would be to attack, defend, or flee, they're still able to exit or get help. Same for once they leave that function and they're just moving around the map, or talking to NPCs. From what I've found, starting a thread that waits for "exit" to be entered is the best way to do that. If I'm wrong, please let me know! If not, please explain (or show me a guide) how I'm supposed to go about this because none of my ideas have worked.

I've attempted using the threading module, and _thread. I may not have implemented them correctly, and I have no code to show for my attempts as I just trashed it when it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game doesn't have to do any work in the background, so you do not need to spawn any additional threads.  The main loop of your program will listen for user input, perform the action, and then prompt the user for their next action.  It should look something like this:

```
while True:
    input = get_user_input()
    if input == 'exit':
        break
    next_actions = modify_game_state(input)
    print "You can now do: %s" % next_actions
```

Edit: You should not have more than one thread accept user input.  It's possible for one of the threads to gobble information that was intended for the other, so no matter what solution you decide on, don't add a thread that just checks if the user input was "exit", unless it reads all of the user input.

Comment: With the complexity of what I'm planning to do, adding the "if exit" line every time it asks for input it would be incredibly repetitive, something that is not suggested to do by experienced programmers from what I've seen.

Comment: You could wrap it in a `check_exit(input)` function.  If you have to check for "exit" everywhere you request user input, then there's no way around repetitiveness.  Another note: your program may become a lot cleaner if you only accept input in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at this, I feel like an absolute idiot.

The proper way to handle this would be calling a function that accepts input and checks it against different expected strings or numerical values.

I just thought I'd answer this in a little more clear way than Stu did.